# Why does one count a loop as a double in graph degree?

Tags: graph-theory

Why does one count a loop as a double in graph degree?

Rather than just as a single?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)):

> a vertex with a loop "sees" itself as an adjacent vertex from both ends of the edge thus adding two, not one, to the degree.

Or perhaps this is just a feature of undirected graphs.

However, I wonder, what's the usefulness of counting a loop as a double in undirected graph?

Comment: Do we${}{}{}{}$?

Comment: The wiki seems to describes it well, the vertex is its own input as well as output in case of loop in undirected graphs, so...

Answer (score 5):

A basic result of graph theory is the *degree sum formula*:
$$\sum_{v \in V} \deg v = 2 \lvert E \rvert$$
This formula holds on loop-graphs only if we let  $\deg v = 2$ for any loop $v$. For a simple example, consider the graph consisting of just one loop.

Comment: But I'm not sure if it's correct to argue that "since the degree sum formula holds, then one must count loops as two". What I'm more about asking, what practical purpose does it serve to count them as two?

Comment: It's not "since the degree sum formula holds", but "since we want the degree sum formula to still hold". We need to decide between $\deg v = 1$ and $\deg v = 2$ for a loop $v$: the easiest choice is the one that doesn't break the formula.

Comment: This way the degree of a vertex is a local property. This way it doesn't need to "know" that two connections it has happen to be the two ends of a single edge. If you have a complicated drawing of a graph, the vertex degree is easy to determine just by counting how many lines meet at the vertex. You don't have to follow all those lines to make sure none of them join up. It is just easier that way, and leads to neater formulas.