# Why does vertex Z have a degree of 5 in here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]
There are only 4 edges to vertex Z, so why does it have a degree of 5?

Comment: The loop counts as $2$. Look at the edges very near to $z$.

Comment: Why is the loop counted as 2?

Comment: To preserve the rule that twice the number of edges is the sum of the vertex degrees.

Comment: The loop is counted as 2 just to avoid contradiction in proving the Sum of degree theorem.

Comment: So it's something mathematicians made up to foolproof their theorem?

Comment: It is explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875780/why-do-you-count-a-loop-as-a-double-in-graph-degree

Comment: Consider the case of directed graphs.  The out-degree of a vertex would be the number of edges where the vertex appeared as the first entry.  The in-degree of a vertex would be the number of edges where the vertex appeared as the second entry.  Adding these together we get the total degree of the vertex.  You can think of a loop as both leaving and going to the same vertex.  It is counted once for when it leaves, and is counted again for when it goes to the vertex, just like any other edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of edges that have $z$ as a start or end point is $5$. The loop will be counted twice.
 [image]